# Series into list of each character

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas series element like this:

```
test

output:
1    10011
Name: working_days, dtype: object
```

and I want to store each number as an element in a list like this:

```
result 

output:
[1,0,0,1,1]
```

Could you help me with the transformation without getting this as a result:

```
[10011]
```

Comment: Do you have only one element in your Series? `list(test.squeeze())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['10011'], name='working_days')

s.apply(lambda x: list(str(x)))
```

cast the number as a string first, then create a list with the string, which splits the string into individual characters

Comment: If you're starting with a string and end with a list of char. `s.apply(list)` is actually enough

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have strings (your dtype is object), you could use:

```
s = pd.Series(['10011'], name='working_days')

out = s.str.findall(r'\d')
```

Or, if you only have digits (suggestion from @AbdulNiyasPM):

```
out = s.map(list)
```

Output:

```
0    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
Name: working_days, dtype: object
```

Comment: or `s.map(list)`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I added your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function to your series that will split the digits and put them in a list:

```
test.apply(lambda x: list(map(int, str(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy view:

```
>>> test.values.astype(str)[:, None].view('<U1').astype(int).tolist()
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

However if you have only one element in your Series, you can simply do:

```
>>> test.values.astype(str).view('<U1').astype(int).tolist()
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

---

Alternative if you want to explode this list into 5 columns for working days:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']
test = pd.Series(['10011', '00110'])

df = pd.DataFrame(test.values.astype(str)[:, None].view('<U1').astype(int), columns=days)
```

Output:

```
>>> test
0    10011
1    00110
dtype: object

>>> df
  Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
0   1   0   0   1   1
1   0   0   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
s.astype(str).str.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\d)', expand=True).apply(list, axis=1)
```

---

Alternatively,

```
s.astype(str).str.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\d)', expand=True).values.astype(int).tolist()
```

---

Output:

```
# First solution
0    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
dtype: object

# Second solution
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```